# Why can't Java variable names start with a number?

Tags: java

In Java, variable names start with a letter, currency character (`$`) etc. but not with number, `:`, or `.`

Simple question: why is that?

Why doesn't the compiler allow to have variable declarations such as

```
int 7dfs;
```

Comment: The downvote is probably a reflection of the poorly worded title, and the format of the question body. Do consider addressing those.

Comment: @Malinda You have asked a number of questions, if there are solutions which solve your problems, do consider accepting them.

Comment: Because the language rules forbid it! See the JLS.

Comment: This syntax detail of Java has been taken over from C++ and C (and possibly BCPL, I don’t know). It has also spread into many other langauges (not only C#). Since a lot of people know more than one language, a lot of people would be confused if the rules were changed. You *may* change the rules if you’ve got strong reasons; apparently they didn’t have here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because the Java Language [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says so:

> IdentifierChars:
>
> JavaLetter {JavaLetterOrDigit}

So - yes, an identifier must start with a letter; it can't start with a digit.

The main reasons behind that:

- it is simply what most people expect
- it makes **parsing** source code (much) easier when you restrict the "layout" of identifiers; for example it reduces the possible ambiguities between literals and variable names.

Answer (score 44):

Simply put, it would break facets of the language *grammar*.

For example, would `7f` be a variable name, or a floating point literal with a value of `7`?

You can conjure others too: if `.` was allowed then that would clash with the *member selection operator*: would `foo.bar` be an identifier in its own right, or would it be the `bar` field of an object instance `foo`?

Comment: Hmm, nice and direct answer.

Comment: I like your examples, they show the motivation behind this design.

Comment: very nice answer.