# json variable name starts with number

Tags: spring-boot, jackson2

example json

```json
{
"11var":"value1",
"11var2":"val2",
"11var3":"val3",
"11var4":"val444",
"11var5":"val5",
.....
}
```

how to convert this to a pojo in latest spring boot and jackson setup?

PS: I know we can do `@JsonProperty("11var")` and so on for all variables. my point what are the other ways. and also main issue here we cant start variable names with numbers in java check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761101/why-cant-java-variable-names-start-with-a-number)

Comment: If you already know of *a* solution and you want to find alternatives, then it usually helps to explain **why** you want alternatives. What disadvantage does the known-working solution have that you want to avoid?

Comment: disadvantage is writing @JsonProperty("11var") @JsonProperty("11var2") @JsonProperty("11var3") think we have 60 variables like this, it will be so many fields and so many jsonproperty, maybe @customJsonProperty or any other way around to make it more easy to read and work with.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil use websites like https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate those classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and jackson `objectMapper`

```
String json = "{\"11var\":\"value1\",\"11var2\":\"val2\",\"11var3\":\"val3\",\"11var4\":\"val444\",\"11var5\":\"val5\"}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
System.out.println(map.get("11var"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson Custom Serialization/Deserialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

And register it to the class level

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ItemSerializer.class)
public class Item {
    ...
}
```